# I should not allow user1 to access user2 by changing url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using form authentication and its wrking fine.But after user1 log's in he wil be displayed user1.aspx page but if he changes the url after logging in he can access user2 page also this should not happen so ive made changes in web config file like this

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms
        name=".LOGIN" 
        cookieless="UseCookies"
        loginUrl="LOGIN.aspx"/>

    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>


  <location path="~/CabScheduler/User1/User1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>



  <location path="~/CabScheduler/User2/User2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>




  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

IN the login page--

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            bool validLogin = false; 

            validLogin = IsValidUser(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
            int UserId = FindRoleId(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
            if (validLogin) 

            {       
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), false); 
                if(UserId ==1)
                    Response.Redirect("~/User1/User1.aspx");
                else
                    Response.Redirect("~/User2/User2.aspx");
        }


            else 

                lblInformation.Text = "Incorrect Login Information"; 
        }
```

Tell me what am i missing or doing wrong.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Authentication should not rely on URLs.

Comment: are you not doing any authoriziation checks anywhere? ?

Comment: On a side-note: this reeks of bad design. Both pages are probably quite similar, so why not have one `CabScheduler.aspx` page on which you display the appropriate data based on the `UserId`?

Comment: remember to send me an invite when your site reaches 100 users.

Comment: My question is how do i not allow users to access other users page by modifying the Url..thnks

Comment: You can't stop users manually modifying the url. The design needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Store the userId in a `Session`, and check if the id is valid for the current page on those pages.

```
Session["userId"] = UserId;
```

And on the page itself:

```
if (Session["userId"] != xxx)
    Redirect("somewhere");
```

Please fill in with appropriate values.

Comment: He didn't ask anything so what are you answering... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

In `User1.aspx` OnLoad event check current user is authenticated to access this page or not and handle accordingly.

On User1.aspx onLoad event check:

```
 if(UserId !=1)
  {
    //redirect to login page
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
 <location path="~/CabScheduler/User2/User2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
                <allow users="user2" />
                <deny users="*, ?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>


    <location path="~/CabScheduler/User1/User1.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="user1" />
                <deny users="*, ?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

Comment: thank u ..but the users can still access others page by changing url